# How get the text inside a paragraph with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to get the text inside p tag

```
 <p id="paragraph">Some text</p>
```

And i want to store the text in JavaScript variable like this

```
 var text = "Some text";
```

I read that i have to add

```
 var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHtml;
```

But the value of the variable is NULL or Undefined and i did also like this

```
 var text = document.getElementById("paragraph")[0].innerHtml;
```

And i had the same problem !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your example you are using incorrect property name, must be [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)(***note*** - case sensitivity `HTML` not `Html`) not `innerHtml`

```
var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML
                                                     ^^^^
```

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use `.textContent` to get the text to make sure you don't get extra markup in your text variable.

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraph");
var text = paragraph.textContent ? paragraph.textContent : paragraph.innerText;//IE uses innerText
```

> innerHTML returns the HTML as its name indicates. Quite often, in order to retrieve or write text within an element, people use innerHTML. textContent should be used instead. Because the text is not parsed as HTML, it's likely to have better performance. Moreover, this avoids an XSS attack vector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score 4):

```
var text = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML;
```